# Debug CakePHP HttpSocket data being sent in get

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, http-get

Is there a way to see the raw data being sent in a `HttpSocket->get()`? I get the response from the server but I can't tell if the headers I am sending are formatted correctly or if there are any default headers being sent that I need to override.

```
$options = array(
  'header' => array(
    'OSLC-Core-Version' => '2.0',
    'Accept' => 'application/xml'
  )
);

$HttpSocket = new HttpSocket();
$results = $HttpSocket->get($url, null, $options);
```

The returned data contains the raw returned information, I am looking for a way to debug the raw data before it is sent to the remote server.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can find all the details (including headers) of the last request in [`HttpSocket::$request`](http://api.cakephp.org/2.4/class-HttpSocket.html#%24request).

```
$HttpSocket = new HttpSocket();
$results = $HttpSocket->get($url, null, $options);

debug($HttpSocket->request);
```